# Linear programming over a finite field

Tags: reference-request, linear-programming, integer-programming, constraint-satisfaction

I have a system of equations $Ax = b$ over some finite field $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and want to find a feasible solution. I'm sure this problem is NP-hard, but I'm struggling to find any literature on the subject. Does this problem have a name? What is known about the computational complexity of this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Your problem, solving a system of linear equations, can be solved using an ancient algorithm, [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination), which works over all fields.

Note that linear programming is more general, allowing also inequalities. It is not entirely clear, however, how the order should be defined over a finite field.